# xcode 8.3 after update: error class __tuple

Tags: c++, xcode

I ran into this issue when I updated XCode 8.3 (I should not do it, I know).

[image]

I searched for days for a solution, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think Xcode8.3 broke c++, I currently cant do anything unless I print something after each line of my code,and endl must be used

Comment: I solved ... I uninstalled xcode 8.3 and installed the previous version